# Не корректно строится запрос в JPA repository

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Есть некая сущность допустим Случай. У этой сущности есть так же вложенная сущность, допустим МедСлучай. В нем есть так же вложенная сущность Шаг, в которой, вложенная сущность Диагноз.

У меня стоит задача: выбрать все id из Случая в которых Шаг != null и Диагноз != null

Вроде бы все легко.
Пишу

```
@Query(select с.id from Случай с where c.МедСлучай.Шаг is not null and с.МедСлучай.Шаг.Диагноз is not null)
```

В итоговой выборке попадаются дубли id.
Понимаю что можно отсеять distinctom, но так же понимаю, что скорее всего проблема в join которые jpa делает под капотом. Как можно исправить?

Comment: Похоже что в данном случае лучше всё-таки использовать `distinct` или как вариант возвращать `Set<Id>`

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что отношение случай-медслучай или медслучай-шаг является отношением OneToMany. Тогда неудивительно, что появляются дубли id, ведь несколько медслучаев или шагов может относиться к случаю

Comment: Отношение случай - медслучай OneToOne, отношение Мед случай - Шаг - manyToOne. Отношение шаг - диагноз ManyToOne